# Rails, Spree: How to check if a product belongs to a parent category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have the following structure in spree:

- Taxon a

  - Taxon a.1

    - Taxon a.1.1

      - Product 1
      - Product 2
      - Product 3

I need to know if there is a optimal way to list all the taxons of the products including the parents.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list the taxons a product belongs to (I'm not clear if that's what you're after), an option is to take advantage of helper methods in the `acts_as_nested_set` functionality that Spree uses for hierarchical taxons.

```
product = Spree::Product.includes(:taxons).find_by(slug: 'gift-card')
product.taxons.map { |taxon| taxon.self_and_ancestors.map(&:name).join(' > ') }

=> ["Christmas Promotions > Last Minute > Gift Cards", "Digital Products > Gift Cards"]
```

Have a look at all the methods available for nested sets for other ideas of how you can do this and similar things: https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/wiki/Awesome-nested-set-cheat-sheet

Comment: I think this is a better approach. In my case I have to search from top to down so I used self_and_descendants. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good approach in the following post: [Spree: intersection between taxons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790067/spree-intersection-between-taxons)

Adding a search scope to the prodcut model:

```
add_search_scope :in_taxon do |taxon|
  Spree::Product.joins(:taxons).where(Taxon.table_name => { :id => taxon.id }).
  order("spree_products_taxons.position ASC")
end
```

Then:

Spree::Product.all.in_taxon(Spree::Taxon.find_by_name('Taxon a'))

Will list all the products inside the referred taxon.